# How to quickly localize storyboard on the fly?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard, swift3

I am trying to localize my app using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1.

I am trying to localze the app using both storyboard(main.strings(German)) and programatically using `"NSLocalizedString"`.

I am able to localize programatically using `"NSLocalizedString"` using following code

```
func localized(lang:String) ->String {

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName:  nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
```

But I am stuck with the localizations which are defined in storyboard. I have defined localised string in main.strings(German).

```
/* Class = “IBUILabel”; text = “Date :”; ObjectID = “0sh-CK-26C”; */
“0sh-CK-26C.text” = “Datum :”;
```

Is there any way to localize the storyboard on run time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, the best way to localize a Storyboard is-
You should first finish the design work in local language and then localize your storyboard in the desired language. Then export .xliff file and replace all the texts in the desired language. And then again import the .xliff file to your project.
And you are done...!

Comment: Thank You..But how should I change language of storyboard on the fly (ex. on button click)

Comment: If you want to do it on a click of button then you can only do it from code only. You can not change storyboard on the fly. If you want to change the storyboard then you must need to re-launch your app.

Comment: Ohh got it..can you please share how to change language of storyboard on button click...considering relaunch case

Comment: When user changes language from menu on button click just change the value in NSUserDefault for key 'AppleLanguages' and ask user to relaunch app. 
e.g. : 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ru", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

Comment: Thank you..can we relaunch app programatically ?

Comment: No, you can only force quit your app. But can't re-launch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130942/discussion-between-krishna-datt-shukla-and-sss).